# R Shiny - How to get levels of one variable with dataframe and variable as inputs (reactive input)

Tags: r, shiny

I'm creating a shiny app, but I'm quite new to R and Shiny.
I would like to have an input which permit me to choose one level among all levels of a variable.
The variable is already an input and the dataframe where the variable is is also an input.
Here is a part of my code in UI :

```
selectInput("dataset", "Dataset :", choices = ls()),
selectInput("variable", "Variable X :", choices = NULL),
selectInput("level", "Level :", choices = NULL)
```

And here is my server code :

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
  col <- colnames(get(input$dataset))
  updateSelectInput(session, "variable", choices = col)
  })
  observe({
  var <- (input$dataset)$(input$variable)
  lvl <- levels(as.factor(var))
  updateSelectInput(session, "level", choices = lvl)
  })
```

I would like to get some help about how to write my object var because (input$a)$(input$b) doesn't work and same with [[ ]]. Is there a simple solution to this ? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested code:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    get(input$dataset)
  })

  observe({
    col <- colnames(data())
    updateSelectInput(session, "variable", choices = col)
  })

  observeEvent(input$data, {
    var <- data()[[input$variable]]
    lvl <- levels(as.factor(var))  
    updateSelectInput(session, "level", choices = lvl)
  })
}
```

You need four things to solve your problem: (1) the name of the dataframe, (2) the names of the columns in the dataframe, (3) the name of the column you want to use as a factor, and (4) the values of the variable you've chosen that are present in the data.  You've assumed that the value of `input$data` gives you both (1) and (4).  It doesn't.  It only gives you (1).  At some point, you've got to tell Shiny (and R) about what the dataframe identified by `input$data` contains.  Hence my use of the reactive object `data()` to provide the actual contents of the dataset.

Consider `unique()` as a simpler way of getting your factor levels than `levels(as.factor())`.

Comment: Thanks a lot it did work with your code except "observeEvent" was changed to "observe". And thanks also for "unique" function I didn't know this